# How do you upgrade your Unity license from Plus to Pro?

Tags: unity, licensing

If I buy a Plus license for Unity for only one month, can I upgrade that license from Plus to Pro in the next month? Or I am in am annual commitment to renew only the Plus license?

If I need to upgrade from Plus license to Pro license a month after publication, what do I do?

Comment: This looks like a question you should ask a Unity account manager — they'll be able to give you the most trustworthy and up to date information about their particular licensing policies, and are very unlikely to try to stand in the way of you giving their business more money. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support question with problems akin to [does product X have feature Y](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2399/33287).

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in [the FAQ of the Unity Plus License](https://store.unity.com/products/unity-plus?_ga=2.156144252.619689513.1552578844-60693781.1528458274#faqs):

> **What happens if I upgrade to a higher tier during my commitment period?**
>
> If you upgrade during a commitment period, you will have to commit for a new period of at least 12 months. For example, if you choose to upgrade to Unity Pro 6 months into a 12 month subscription to Plus, you will have to start a new 12 month commitment period for Pro. The prior commitment period for Plus will be removed.

So yes, you can upgrade from Plus to Pro at any time. When you do that, your Plus subscription ends (even if still in the commitment period) and a new Pro subscription begins (restarting the commitment period).

**Note to future visitors:** Back in our time Unity used to change their licensing terms quite often. They might still be doing that in your time. So you might want to verify that the FAQ still says what it said back in March 2019.

Comment: Thanks guys  if I bought  plus for one month so  in Upgrade to pro I have to buy pro for one year? is it correct?

Comment: @shahindezfouli Yes, that's what it says.